# Laravel One To Many Relationship Trying To Get Property Of Non-object

Tags: php, laravel, model, one-to-many

I'm building relationship model between Siswa (student) and Kelas (class), which one Kelas has many Students (hence One to Many). Here is the code :

Show.php view

```
<tr>
    <th>Kelas</th>
    <td>{{$siswa->kelas->nama_kelas}}</td>
</tr>
```

Siswa.php model

```
class Siswa extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'siswa';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nisn',
        'nama_siswa',
        'tgl_lahir',
        'jns_klmin',
        'id_kelas',
        'id_hobi',
    ];

    public function kelas(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Kelas', 'id_kelas');
    }
}
```

Kelas.php model

```
class Kelas extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'kelas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_kelas'
    ];

    public function siswa(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Siswa', 'id_kelas');
    }
}
```

I think I'm already called method kelas in model Siswa accordingly, but $siswa->kelas->nama_kelas is defined as a non-object. Anyone can give some enlightment? Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This is the show controller :

```
public function show(Siswa $siswa){
    return view('siswa.show', compact('siswa'));
}
```

In show parameter I'm using route model binding to find passing $id in RouteServiceProvider, which I modified :

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);
    $router->model('siswa', 'App\Siswa');
}

public function map(Router $router)
{
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
        ], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `belongsTo()` method will return `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo` instance. In order to get the `Kelas` instance you have to do it like so:

```
$siswa->kelas->first()->nama_kelas
```

Hope this help!

Comment: what's first() method do? It seems work, but I get "Call to a member function first() on a non-object" error

Comment: Well, basically it will retrieve the first matching query constraint. in your case, it will retrieve the first matching record from `kelas` table where the `id` is equal to the current `id_kelas` of `Siswa` instance.

Comment: That means your `$siswa` is not an Eloquent model instance. How do you pass your `$siswa` data into the view?

Comment: If you passed the `$siswa` that way, it supposed to be working. Since the route binding will make sure that the passed parameter will alway be an instance of `App\Siswa` class. Can you show me the complete error message? And which part of the code thrown that error?

Comment: now you mentione it... if $siswa wasn't passed to show controller, another column like Nama (name) and NISN (student number) should show error too... but the error comes from kelas which is an independent table, linked by foreign key, where Nama and NISN is a column in tabel Siswa...

I've changed it to original form without model binding and it works... so the problem either from model binding, one to many relationship, or both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127996/discussion-between-rayan-suryadikara-and-risan-bagja-pradana).